# How can I add fixed-width space to beginning of HStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui, hstack

In SwiftUI I am adding buttons to an HStack. I want a space of a fixed width at the beginning of the HStack. Currently the buttons are directly up against the left edge of the screen and I want a space of 64px before the first button. I cannot seem to find an answer to this, my Google-Fu may be failing me.

Here is what I have:

```
struct MyView: View {
   var body: some View {
      HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12, content: {
         Button(action: doThis) {
            Image("this").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         }.frame(width: 38, height: 38, alignment: .center)
         Button(action: doThat) {
            Image("that").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         }.frame(width: 38, height: 38, alignment: .center)
         Spacer()
      })
   }
   
   func doThis() {}
   
   func doThat() {}
   
}
```

Comment: Try setting the frame of the spacer, and put it before all the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some `padding` on the left.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12, content: {
         Button(action: doThis) {
            Image("this").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         }.frame(width: 38, height: 38, alignment: .center)

         .padding(.leading, 64) /// here!
        
        
         Button(action: doThat) {
            Image("that").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
         }.frame(width: 38, height: 38, alignment: .center)
         Spacer()
      })
   }
   
   func doThis() {}
   
   func doThat() {}
   
}
```

| Before | After |
| --- | --- |
| [image: No space on left] | [image: Space on left] |